# Git remote repository & folder structure

Tags: 16.04, git

I'm running Git under Ubuntu 16.04.

I created a `git` user, a folder `/var/git` and, let say a repository `/var/git/project1/myrepo.git`

I also created a `pair of keys` and added the public key in the git `authorized_keys`

Under my windows pc I want to clone my remote repository.

First problem : I would like to use `ssh://git@10.15.3.6/project1/myrepo.git`

But of course, it's not working because it's searching `project1/myrepo.git` under the root (`/` just after ip address)

So under `/home/git` I created a symbolic link that points `myproject` to `/var/git/myproject`

And now I can use `ssh://git@10.15.3.6/~/project1/myrepo.git`

But it is quite annoying to put `~/`

How can I do to avoid that and allow me to use something simple like `ssh://git@10.15.3.6/project1/myrepo.git` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a symbolic link to the `project1` folder:

`sudo ln -s /var/git/project1 /project1`